# magento 1.9 paypal express on cart page to checkout page

Tags: php, magento, paypal

I am using magento 1.9 and I have paypal express button that works on product page and cart page.I want to know how can I place the same button on checkout page.

In the admin we only have two options (product page and cart page )as shown in the attached image.

I want the same button as on the cart page to be on the checkout page.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDGG0.png)
Thank you
Sarvesh

Answer (score 0):

In checkout page there is no need of put PayPal button. Because its already display in Payment Method section. Customer just need to select PayPal payment method and it will work fine.